# Redirect output of a .bat file run by a python script to GUI, and making that script into EXE

Tags: python, user-interface, batch-file, wxpython

I have currently written a Python file that creates a GUI using wxPython, allows the user to enter some fields, then runs a .bat file in some other location, sending those parameters. The .bat file prints a lot of output on the command prompt, and I would like to either redirect that to a text box in my GUI, or have my GUI pop a new command prompt to run the .bat file. I'm writing this with the intention to make it a standalone .exe file, so which option is better, and how can I implement it?

EDIT: I was able to redirect the output from the Python file itself by creating a new class specifically for it:

```
class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self,aWxTextCtrl):
        self.out=aWxTextCtrl
    def write(self,string):
        self.out.WriteText(string)
```

However, it doesn't handle the output from the .bat file I'm running using subprocess.Popen.

Comment: here's [an example that shows how to display output from a subprocess in a GUI (using gtk)](https://gist.github.com/zed/8a255e81eb87431c0e63). You could adapt the same technique for wxPython.

Comment: to create a standalone .exe-file, you could use [PyInstaller that supports wxPython](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/SupportedPackages)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. If I want to create the standalone executable, will I need to include the .bat files?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up something using subprocess and wx where  I ran ping, traceroute and a couple of other things and redirected their output to my text control. It's a little tricky, but not too bad. I wrote up a tutorial on my blog about it:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/05/python-running-ping-traceroute-and-more/

I am using a redirect function much like your own, then after I have the redirection set up, I do something like the following:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------   
def pingIP(self, ip):
    proc = subprocess.Popen("ping %s" % ip, shell=True, 
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
    print
    while True:
        line = proc.stdout.readline()                        
        wx.Yield()
        if line.strip() == "":
            pass
        else:
            print line.strip()
        if not line: break
    proc.wait()
```

Comment: note: if `.readline()` blocks; it will also block the GUI. You might need a background thread that reads the output and enqueues it e.g., using `wxCallAfter()`.

Comment: That's true, although I haven't actually had that happen in my apps as of yet

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to call your script
Example calling the 'ls' command on Linux:

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call(['ls', '-l'])
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 0 Jun 17 18:37 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 0 Jun 17 18:37 file2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 0 Jun 17 18:37 file3
0
```